# wgetでダウンロードした漢字を含むファイル名が文字化け

Tags: windows, command-line

いくつかwgetに関するQAなどを参照して解決に至らなかったので質問します。

タイトルの通り
**【wgetでダウンロードした漢字を含むファイル名が文字化け】**
され、解決策を探しています。

指定URL配下のファイルを再帰的にダウンロードするwgetコマンドをbatに記述しています。
そのbatをvc++のCreateProcessから実行しています。

> 環境 Windows Server 2012 R2
>   処理フロー
>   VC++ -> bat -> wget

batのコマンドは下記のとおりです

> 省略...
>
> rem UTF-8
>   chcp 65001
>
> wget -e robots=off --random-wait --timeout=10 --tries=1
>   --html-extension -nv -R exe,zip,css,js,jpg,jpeg,gif,png,mpg,mpeg,au,mp3 -x -P
>   'ダウンロード保存先ディレクトリパス' -o '標準出力ログ保存先ファイルパス'
>   --restrict-file-names=nocontrol 'ダウンロード先URL' --no-check-certificate --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" -r -l 2 -np
>
> rem SJIS
>   chcp 932
>
> 省略...

ダウンロード自体は問題なく実行されるのですが、
漢字を含むhtmlのダウンロードファイルを確認すると
ファイル名が文字化けしています。

> 例.縺←繧らｷ粋晞匱.html

ただし、**-oオプションで保存した標準出力ログには正しいファイル名**が出力されていました。

何か良い解決策はないでしょうか？

Comment: chcp 65001を抜くと何か不都合ありますか？

Comment: take88さん。補足します。chcp65001は元々ありませんでした。文字化けが解消しないので付与しました。あってもなくても結果は変わらないです。

Comment: そのダウンロード先URLは提示できますか？

Comment: 当てずっぽうですがダウンロード先はファイル名がUTF-8で、Windowsのファイル名はSJIS(CP932) なのですが、--restrict-file-names=nocontrol としているので何も加工せずUTF-8でファイルが作成されていると思います。詳しくないのですが --restrict-file-names の値をnocontrol以外に何かに変えてみるとへんかありませんか？`unix` `windows` `acscii` `lowercase` `uppercase` が指定できるようです。

Comment: `--remote-encoding=SJIS`とかつけたら変化ありませんかね？

Answer (score 1):

`--restrict-file-names=nocontrol` のところを `--restrict-file-names=nocontrol,windows,ascii` とすると、少なくともパーセントエンコードした形(本来の文字の情報を復元できる形)で取得できるかも。

Comment: sakuroさん。上記で試してみたところ投稿のような文字化けになってしまいました(%がつくURLエンコードだとまだやりようはあったのですが)。ありがとうございました。